# Divergence of sum containing number of divisors function.

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Show that 
$\sum_{n\ge{2}}\frac{d(n)}{n\log^2n}$ 
is divergent.

I've tried to do this using the comparison test, i.e looking for a divergent series with a summand smaller than the summand in the given sum, but the obvious choices ($\frac{1}{n\log^2n}$) seem to converge. Can the Abel test and the divergence of $\sum_{n\ge{2}}d(n)$ (which is determined by the limit as $x\rightarrow\infty$ of the asymptotic expansion) bee used to somehow state that the given sum is divergent? If not what test should be used?

Comment: Did you happen to mean $\log\log{n}$ instead of $\log^2n$?

Comment: @barakmanos I don't think so, otherwise the question would have been trivial.

Comment: $log^2n$ is correct.

Comment: what is the source of the problem? what is in the chapter where this problem appears?

Comment: it appears after the asymptotic expansion for $\sum_{n\le{x}}d(n)$ found with the hyperbola method in the course of proving the prime number theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer.

If you prove that you are allowed to use Cauchy's condensation test, you can observe that

$$\sum_{n\geq 2} \frac{2^nd(2^n)}{2^n \log^2 2^n} = \frac{1}{\log^2 2}\sum_{n\geq 2} \frac{n+1}{n^2}$$

is a divergence series, hence your series is divergent.

Comment: This assumes that the original sequence is non-increasing.

Comment: Thanks. I've yet to come across the Cauchy's condensation test, but I'll read up on it and see if I can figure it out. Any alternative test that can be used?

Comment: I've done some reading and I think I understand why the test can be applied in this case and how to apply it.Thanks.

Comment: I found a complete proof that this series is divergent, I will post it in future.